# question about plural and possesives

Tags: possessives, plural-forms

Is this dialogue correct? (regarding plural and possessives) Thank you.

> "I like it; keep going. Would you want some more clovers? I can bring you some," the fairy said.
>
> "Yes! Thank you... What's your name?"
>
> "My name? Ah, the labels! Why do you want to put labels on everything? I am me, a fairy in the middle of a grove of clovers, and you are drawing them. You can call me the Clovers' Fairy. Ok?"
>
> Suddenly, Luna found herself in a grove...of Giants Clovers.
>
> "Sorry, you're right. How did you create that?"

Comment: This looks like a request to proofread and correct your work. Please note that such questions are usually closed here unless you can identify a specific problem and describe what you have already done to answer your question.

Comment: I've asked about 'clover' and 'clovers', looked for the answer online, and I had 2 beta readers and one editor giving good answers without explanation. I thought I could ask here because I find this forum full of resources and people answering very clearly. I'm sorry if it's not allowed to ask for explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BrE we say 'a field of clover'. I've never heard the word 'clovers'. So the line 'Would you want some more clovers?' is not idiomatic, though it might be eccentric and endearing coming from a fairy. We pick 'clover flowers', so the fairy might offer more clover flowers.

('Would you want some more' is probably not quite right here. 'Would you like...' or 'Do you want...' might be better.)

We would say, 'a grove of clover' (if we were small enough) and we would want to be called 'the Clover Fairy'. Luna might find herself in a grove of giant clover (if she were small enough). It would from then on be called the *clover grove*. You can use capitals for impact - a grove of Giant Clover - the first time it is mentioned, but not *every* time.

('How did you create that' doesn't sound like a child. A child would ask 'How did you make that?' or, more likely, 'How did you *do* that?' But maybe Luna's not a child.)

Comment: Great! Thank you! Luna is not a child, but she's living a magical experience. The point is: Luna has a 'normal human size,' but I want to show there is not 'a field of clover' but a grove because of the Giant Clover. I don't understand: "a grove of giant clover" when it supposed to have a lot of clover. No plural here?

Comment: Clover is one of those words that is its own plural.

Comment: ok, thank you! I didn't know.

Comment: @Simon Actually, I suspect that "clover" has a plural form of "clovers" and is similar to fish, where we talk about a "school of fish," meaning many more than one of instance of one kind of fish, and "all the fishes of the sea," meaning multiple kinds of fish. For example, Wikipedia says "the most common clovers are ..." Of course, this is being fussy. In the context of this question, "clover" is the standard plural form.

Comment: So, 'clover' has a plural form, but it wouldn't be correct in this context. Thank you Jeff Morrow.

Comment: @JeffMorrow You are quite right. My apologies!

Comment: @Patricia I think it might be more helpful to say that "clover" is one of a small class of nouns typified by "fish" in which the plural is usually expressed by a singular form, but the plural form exists though used only in certain special cases. I am sorry, but I am unable to articulate a rule for identifying which nouns belong to the class. The ones that come to my mind have Germanic roots through Anglo-Saxon and pertain to living creatures that are frequently found in large aggregations, but that is a guess. "Grass," wheat," and "rye" are further examples.